# How do I force Chrome to ignore ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH?

Tags: google-chrome, http

Chrome enforces this error and refuses to render. I'm trying to access an old router and I'm getting ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH errors in the console. I looked at the request with Curl and it works fine. The entire document loads with closing `</HTML>` tag, but Chrome refuses to render the page! How can I force Chrome to ignore the error?

Here are the headers from Curl:

```
$ curl -i "http://192.168.16.1" -H "Host: 192.168.16.1"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server:
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Sun, 08 Sep 2002 12:27:04 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 14 Feb 2007 07:54:55 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Content-Length: 14498
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Here is the end of Curl output:

```
</DIV></BODY></HTML>
curl: (18) transfer closed with 29 bytes remaining to read
```